# How to display data with yajra datatable many to many relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra datatable. I want to display data and filter data with the president name
I have 3 tables

```
1- Planes = id, title, description.

2- presidents = id, P_name.

3- Plane_president = plane_id , president_id
```

Plane Model:

```
public function president()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(President::class);
    }
```

President Model:

```
public function planes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Plane::class);
}
```

My Controller :

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
            $query = Plane::with('presidents')->selectRaw('distinct planes.*');
            return $this->dataTable
                ->eloquent($query)
                ->addColumn('P_name', function (Plane $plane) {
                    return $plane->presidents->map(function($president) {
                        return str_limit($president->P_name);
                    })->implode('&lt;br&gt;');
                })
                ->make(true);
        }

        return view('planes.index');
    }
```

js code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#search').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ route("plane.index") }}',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'main_point', name: 'main_point'},
            {data: 'presidents[, ].P_name', name: 'president'},
        ]
    });
    </script>
```

I have this error

```
message "Undefined property: App\\Http\\Controllers\\PlaneController::$dataTable"
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DataTables::` to make `datatable` and you were missing `->rawColumns(['p_name'])` i added that

```php
if ($request->ajax()) {
    $plane = Plane::with('presidents')->selectRaw('distinct planes.*')->get();
    return \DataTables::of($plane)
        ->addColumn('p_name', function ($plane) {
            return implode(', ', $plane->presidents->pluck('P_name')->toArray());
        })
        ->rawColumns(['p_name'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

in javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#search').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ route("plane.index") }}',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'main_point', name: 'main_point'},
            {data: 'p_name', name: 'p_name'}, // manipulate data of this column in server side here just echo like this
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it as below.

```
return datatables()->eloquent($query);
```

Please check the [document](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/quick-starter). and for display president name I would suggest.

```
implode(', ', $plane->presidents->pluck('P_name')->toArray())
```

Comment: I have this error when I want to search for data `DataTables warning: table id=search - Exception Message:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'planes.presidents' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select distinct planes.* from `planes` where (LOWER(`planes`.`id`) LIKE %j% or LOWER(`planes`.`main_point`) LIKE %j% or LOWER(`planes`.`presidents`) LIKE %j%)) count_row_table)`